# arithmetic mean of numbers divisible by 3

Tags: c, arrays

I understand this is not the best piece of code and I'm not looking to improve it - only to understand it.

I'm not sure about the s=i=k=0 expression and the integer k and of course then if (k) s/=k; is totally dubious.

Thank you.

```
main()
{
int a[100], i,k,n;
double s;
while (1)
{       
    printf ("Enter the number of elements:");
    scanf ("%d", &n);



if (n<0 || n>100) break;

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("a[%d]:", i);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

}

for (s=i=k=0; i<n; i++)
    if (a[i]%3 == 0)
    {
        s+=a[i];
        k++;
    }

    if (k) s/=k;
    printf("s=%.2f\n", s);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

> s=i=k=0

is same as

```
s = 0;
i = 0;
k = 0;
```

Remember that multiple assignment on one line is done right to left

```
s=(i=(k=0))

k = 0 // first
i = k // second
s = i // third
```

`!` `double` variables should be initialized with `0.0` instead of `0`.

---

> s /= k;

is same as

```
s = s / k;
```

You can do this shortening with a lot of operator, like `*,+,-,%,&,|,...`

---

```
if ( k ) equals if ( k!=0 )
```

and

```
if ( !k ) equals if ( k==0 )
```

> But its better to use `(k)` and `(!k)` just for boolean variables for better reading / understandong of code.

---

> arithmetic mean of numbers divisible by 3

```
if (a[i]%3 == 0)
{
    s+=a[i];
    k++;
}
```

Checking if variable `a[i]` is multiple of three. If it is, execute body of condition.

Comment: It might help to explain that `if (k)` is the same as `if (0 != k)`.

Comment: Perhaps better not use C language elements in normal English, better just use a wording like in my comment "*is the same*" or "is equal" or alike. Doing as you did (using `==`) might very well confuse somebody ...

Comment: Probably you are right. Iam just accustomed to use these elements everywhere, heh.

Comment: Note that you used `int s = I = k = 0;` where the code in the question omits the `int`, and `s` is a `double`. Your fragment defines a new variable `s` and references pre-existing variables `i` and `k`, which is unusual.  Note that the question uses a mixed mode assignment, some integer, some floating point.

Comment: Sure but its explanation of one lined multiple assignment. Ok ill fix it